# Using wait(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) twice in one method

Tags: java

I'm trying to use "wait(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)" twice in the same method, but when it comes to the second time, it does both of them at the same time. By this, I mean that when I input my second value, it does all of the calculations, but then it loops back to where the first "wait(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)" is, and asks me for another second value.

```
public void calculate(){

    print("Calculate" + "\n", false, new Color(0,204,0));

    print("calculator activated" + "\n" + "please input your first value" + "\n", false, new Color(210, 190, 13));

    try {
        wait(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    } 
    catch (Exception e1) {
    }


    input.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String text1 = input.getText();
            double value1 = Double.parseDouble(text1);

            print(text1 + "\n", false, new Color(0,204,0));

            print("please input your second value" + "\n", false, new Color(210, 190, 13));

            try {
                wait(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            } 
            catch (Exception e1) {
            }

            input.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String text2 = input.getText();
            double value2 = Double.parseDouble(text2);

            print(text2 + "\n", false, new Color(0,204,0));

            doCommand(text2);
            scrollBottom();
            input.selectAll();

            double add = value1 + value2;
            double subtract = value1 - value2;
            double multiply = value1 * value2;
            double divide = value1 / value2;

        print("add = " + add + "\n", false, new Color(210, 190, 13));
        print("subtract = " + subtract + "\n", false, new Color(210, 190, 13));
        print("multiply = " + multiply + "\n", false, new Color(210, 190, 13));
        print("divide = " + divide + "\n", false, new Color(210, 190, 13));

        }


    });
}
    });
}
```

Comment: Can u paste the whole code ? (that cant compile).

Comment: Never write an empty `catch` block.  At the very least, you should call the [printStackTrace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace--) method of the caught exception.  Otherwise, how will you know if something has gone wrong?

Comment: @chenchuk I don't have enough characters for that.

Comment: @VGR I get that, and I'll add it it, but it still doesn't solve my problem. Thanks though

Comment: Is that `wait` method inherited from java.lang.Object?  If it is, you're using it wrong;  the argument to it is a duration in milliseconds, not a key code.  That aside, you must never wait or sleep in an ActionListener, because AWT and Swing depend on the continuous processing of their events for a functioning user interface.  When you wait or sleep, you delay the processing of those events and effectively hang the application.

Comment: @VGR that makes sense, but how else can I wait until the next user input?

Comment: Listeners exist precisely for that purpose.  They tell your program when something has happened, so you don't have to wait for it.  For example, an ActionListener added to a JTextField will have its `actionPerformed` method automatically called when the user presses Enter while the JTextField has focus.